# How to control ActionChains of selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to slide a bar using selenium.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://verify.meituan.com/v2/web/general_page?action=spiderindefence&requestCode=0a64ed1a2b904b3d841c99c253cc639e&platform=1&adaptor=auto&succCallbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2Foptimus-mtsi.meituan.com%2Foptimus%2FverifyResult%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fm.dianping.com%252FPennsylvania%252Fch10%252Fd1%253Ffrom%253Dm_nav_1_meishi&theme=dianping'
browser.get(url)
knob = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")
ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(knob).perform()
tracks = [1, 2, 16, 128, 20, 18, 15]
for x in tracks:
        print(x)
        ActionChains(browser).move_by_offset(x, 0).perform() 
ActionChains(browser).pause(0).release().perform()
```

I tried different tracks but all failed.

I found that the bar will stop for a very short time when sliding an offset, that is, sliding is not smooth.

How to solve this problem?

Can I change the time for each offset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider chaining all of the actions into one execution:

```py
knob = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='yodaBoxWrapper']//div[@id='yodaMoveingBar']")

# Create a dynamic action chain – we'll add to this
my_actions = ActionChains(browser).click_and_hold(knob).pause(0.01)
tracks = [1, 2, 16, 128, 20, 18, 15]
for x in tracks:
    print(x)
    my_actions.move_by_offset(x, 0).pause(0.01)

# At the end, release the knob
my_actions.release()

# Finally, perform
my_actions.perform()
```

Comment: Tried but it does not work. You can test code with my updated url.

Comment: Url isn't giving me any sliding bar... @Chan

Comment: The url is expired and I changed it to another.